# Why missing content/values when using urlopen to crawl data?

Tags: javascript, python, web-crawler, urlopen

I just use following Python codes to crawl data

```
html = urlopen("https://www.hkex.com.hk/?sc_lang=en").read().decode('utf-8') 
print(html)
```

But I missed the content and only got

```
<div class="type value"></div>
```

My goal is to get

```
<div class="type value">HK$24,225M</div>  or HK$24,225M
```

[image]

Comment: wdym by missed the content? You definitelly have to receive the wanted text in the HTML. Do you use regex? How do you get the values that you want?

Comment: It appears as though the values you are looking for are generated using javascript, which will not be present when simply reading HTML.  You should try using Selenium to do this.

Comment: @MaxxikCZ She definitely didn't get the correct data back.  Did you try to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on this website is updated using JavaScript. Try to press Ctrl+U in your browser.

In this example, the data is fetched from `https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/script/data_NBSZ_Turnover_eng.js` or `data_SBSZ_Turnover_eng.js`. (I don't know what you need)

In the future look at the "Network" tab in the developer tools, you can probably find what you need there.